# How to make Material Design Filled text fields In Xamarin Andriod

Tags: xamarin.android, material-design, material-ui

I want to use the material design Filled TextField in Xamarin andriod.Floating label is working Accurate but i want to make the Background color like Give Image. Dint Know how i use @style of Material design to make textfield like this.

[image: This Is The Required OutPut of Material design]

This is the code I use to achieve it:

```
<!-- <item> --> 
<!-- <shape android:shape="rectangle"> --> 
<!-- 1 Draw a 2dp width border around shape @1@ --> 
<!-- <stroke --> 
<!-- android:color="#004d40" --> 
<!-- android:width="2dp" --> <!-- /> --> 
<!-- </shape> --> 
<!-- </item> --> 
<!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color --> 
<item android:bottom="7dp"> 
<shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
<solid android:color="#F8F9FA"/> 
</shape> 
</item> 
</layer-list>
```

Comment: `Dint Know how I use @style of ` what exactly do you mean here? You already have a code and do not know how to use it?

Comment: I Flaoting Label working Good ...But i Dont Know how  i can style Like this Box InputBox in Xamarin Android

Comment: So basically you do not have anything right? Or do you have a java example?

Comment: yes But I Get This Back Background  color by making shape ...but i want to know is this is better approch...because i have got the desire outpout

Comment: Add the code and we can see what you have done so far

Comment: <!-- <item> -->
  <!--   <shape android:shape="rectangle"> -->
  <!--     1 Draw a 2dp width border around shape @1@ -->
  <!--     <stroke -->
  <!--       android:color="#004d40" -->
  <!--       android:width="2dp" -->
  <!--     /> -->
  <!--   </shape> -->
  <!-- </item> -->
  <!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color  -->
  <item
    android:bottom="7dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#F8F9FA"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: i have add this shape

Comment: Always add these things into the question I cannot understand it here as it's non-readable

Comment: i got this salution after posting my Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- <item> -->
  <!--   <shape android:shape="rectangle"> -->
  <!--     1 Draw a 2dp width border around shape @1@ -->
  <!--     <stroke -->
  <!--       android:color="#004d40" -->
  <!--       android:width="2dp" -->
  <!--     /> -->
  <!--   </shape> -->
  <!-- </item> -->
  <!-- Overlap the left, top and right border using background color  -->
  <item
    android:bottom="7dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#F8F9FA"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Add This Code in Drawable and use it by 
       android:background="@drawable/CustomBackGround"